# highcharts - proximate legend items incorrectly assigned (edge case)

Tags: highcharts

This is probably very edge case scenario, but I wanted to know if there is any workaround.
I noticed that when legend align set to `right` and layout is `proximate` and when last data points close to each other and bottom legend item has multiple lines in it, it confuses legend order.

Please take a look into this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/sabira/3gk4dofp/) and the image below:
I'm trying to have legend items ordered by their last value like `test1`,`test2`, `test3`, `test longer text4`, but instead got two last items mixed up. And it happens only when two last data points close to each other. Other times it worked perfectly.
I've tried to play around with legend.maxHeight, but unfortunately it has no effect.

I appreciate any help!
[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what do you want to achieve, but it seems that the `proximate` create your issue. Could you describe what output would you like to get?

Comment: Hi @SebastianWędzel, thanks for looking into it and sorry for not being clear. I am expecting get legend items ordered by their last data point, but in this particular scenario `test longer text4`(in the image above) appear on top of `test3` legend item even though it's value less than `test3` value. I believe it gets pushed bc legend box does not have enough space to place them all in the right order. so I tried to expand the box height using `maxHeight` property, but it didn't help. Probably my assumption is not correct. Hope it make sense!

Comment: It seems that it is the fault of the `styledMode` option because the CSS styling options override the `textOverflow: truncate` option - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemStyle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a3nq8ms0/

Comment: But i'd like to keep `styledMode` as well as wrap the legend item text. When I log allItems names on chart load `console.log('legend', chart.legend.allItems.map(item=> item.name))` names array logs items in proper  order. I've tried going into each legend item element and look into transform` translateY` property and compare it with a previous one and swap if they were unordered, but it didn't work. Something else probably affecting the order. My last thought was to expand `maxHeight` on chart load, but it didn't work either.

Comment: But have you noticed that using the `styledMode` makes that your function doesn't work - the width of the legend is constance, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fdvtoL7s/ and compare to your demo with the resizing. If you want to keep the styledMode (which disables the inline styling) you should try to customize those labels using the CSS.

Comment: I don't think css have something to do with the order of legend items. They should be controlled by `proximate` setting. And even having inline styles and setting chart.legend.itemStyle.textOverflow to `undefined` produces same unordered result.

Comment: if you think that it's a bug - please report it on the Highcharts Github issue channel. The core developers will contact you in this case. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues